# Construct a grammar for the language

Tags: formal-grammars, programming-languages

How can I achieve this. Write a grammar for the language consisting of strings built only of the letters a and b. The strings may have any number of these letters, but the letter combinations bab must be in each string somewhere, and each string must start with a bb. For example, the strings bbababbbaa, bbbaaaababaa, and bbbab are in the language, while a, aabb, baaa, and bbba are not.

Comment: Your language is regular. You can design an NFA for your language, and then convert it to a context-free grammar.

Answer (score -1):

1. The string much start with $ bb $ .
2. There should at least one occurrence of the sub-string $ bab $

Hence, the structure of the regular expression must be something like this:
$$ bb[some \: string]bab[some \: string] $$

and, we can define $ [some \: string] $ something like this:

$$ (a + b)^* $$

which means, there can be any number (including 0) of either a's or b's.
Therefore, the final regex for the word is, 
$$ bb(a+b)^*bab(a+b)^* $$

Comment: Doesn't match $bbab$.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out now.